# Counting the number of compressed files in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, count, grep, hdfs, bigdata

I am trying to count the files that are compressed in an Hdfs folder.
I am using hdfs dfs -count /user/data | grep .snappy --it shows nothing
grep .snappy | hdfs dfs -count /user/data   --it shows all files (even which are not .snappy)

Can I get the proper command to count the .snappy files in this /user/data hdfs path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hdfs dfs -count` command gives following information:

- Directory count
- File count
- Content size
- File name

For e.g., I get following output on my `/tmp/` folder:

```
CMD> hdfs dfs -count  /tmp/
    14           33       193414280395 /tmp
```

Using this command, you cant get the count of `.snappy` files like this:

```
CMD> hdfs dfs -count -v /tmp/*.snappy
```

You will get output like this:

```
DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
       0            1               4623 /tmp/Links.txt.snappy
       0            1             190939 /tmp/inclusions_00000005.snappy
```

To get the count of `.snappy` files, you can also execute following commands:

- Get the count of `.snappy` files directly under a folder:

  Just execute `hadoop fs -ls` command. For e.g. to get number of `.snappy` files under `/user/data` folder, just execute:

  ```
  hadoop fs -ls /user/data/*.snappy | wc -l
  ```
- Recursively get the count of all the `.snappy` files under a folder:

  Execute `hadoop fsck` command. For e.g.:

  ```
  hadoop fsck /user/data/ -files | grep ".snappy" | wc -l
  ```

**EDIT: All files greater than 30 MB**
If you want to find all the files with size greater than or equal to 30 MB (30 *1024 * 1024 = 31457280), you need to execute the following command:

```
hadoop fsck /user/data -files | grep ".snappy" | gawk '{if ($2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $2>=31457280) print $1,$2;}'
```

This will print $1 as file name and $2 as the size of the file.

If you want the count of the files, then just pipe it to `wc -l` as shown below:

```
hadoop fsck /user/data -files | grep ".snappy" | gawk '{if ($2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $2>=31457280) print $1,$2;}' | wc -l
```

Comment: Is there any way to check the above requirement for files that are less than 30Mb

Comment: [root@user~]# hadoop fsck /user/data/ -files | grep ".snappy" | gawk "{if ($2>1024) print $1,$2;}"
gawk: {if (>1024) print ,;}
gawk:      ^ syntax error
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Connecting to namenode via https://ip:port

Comment: any other way I can do this? I really need to get compressed files that are greater than 100Mb

Comment: @Naveen I have updated the answer. I was executing this command on my Windows box. It was working fine. On Linux machines, you need to use single quote for the block in gawk. Please check the updated answer. It worked fine on my Linux VM.

Comment: Manju, its working but its listing all the files. there are more than 1000 files. I just want the number of .snappy files > 30MB

Comment: edited code is working fine for me Manju but, its listing all the files which is more than 500 files. Any way I can just get a count for eg: 500 or so

Comment: If you just want the count of the files, then you need to add `wc -l` at the end like this: hadoop fsck /user/data -files | grep ".snappy" | gawk '{if ($2>=31457280) print $1,$2;}' | wc -l

Comment: Perfect it worked as required. I tried hadoop fsck /user/data -files | gawk '{if ($2 >=31457280) print $1,$2;}' | wc -l
for just counting the files >than 30MB but it gives number greater than the total files in dir

Comment: I want to search recursively. even this is not working for recursive search hadoop fsck /devdata -files | grep "snappy" | gawk '{if ($2 >=52428800) print $1,$2;}' | wc -l

Comment: I have introduced an extra check, "$2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/" to see if 2nd column is a number. Updated the answer. Even now, if you get wrong numbers, then I don't know what's wrong. Its difficult for me to help, remotely :(. Because, for me the same command on both Windows and Linux is working perfectly.

Comment: It worked. Thanks manju and sorry for extending the questions